# Como desenhar uma OBB em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Eu estou tendo sérias dificuldades em desenhar uma OBB.
Segue o código:

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
  height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,

  centro = {
   x:  Math.random() * 150,
   y: Math.random() * 150
  },

  angulo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 361),

  vetorU = {
   x: Math.cos(angulo),
   y: Math.sin(angulo)
  },

  vetorV = {
   x: -vetorU.y, //cos(angulo + 90),
   y: vetorU.x//sin(angulo + 90)
  };

  vetorU.x = vetorU.x * width/12 + centro.x,
  vetorU.y = vetorU.y * width/12 + centro.y,
  vetorV.x = vetorV.x * height/12 + centro.x,

  context.moveTo(vetorU.x + vetorV.x, vetorU.y + vetorV.y);
  context.lineTo(-vetorU.x + vetorV.x, -vetorU.y + vetorV.y);
  context.lineTo(-vetorU.x + (-vetorV.x), -vetorU.y + (-vetorV.y));
  context.lineTo(vetorU.x + (-vetorV.x), vetorU.y + (-vetorV.y));
  context.lineTo(vetorU.x + vetorV.x, vetorU.y + vetorV.y);
  context.stroke(); 
    };
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: Desenhar uma o quê? O que é uma obb?

Comment: Olha esse vídeo. É sobre objetos e colisão. Você vai começar a entender a partir dele. Eu consegui solucionar o problema. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IELWpIGtjRg